# How to send JSON data from front-end JavaScript to the Back-end Server built by using Python Flask

Tags: javascript, python, json, flask

I am using a simple HTML form to get some simple data from the user. I want that data to be first filtered using the JavaScript in the front-end and if everything is Okay, I am converting that gathered data in JSON format using JavaScript in the front-end itself.

**Now what i want is to send that JSON formatted data in the JavaScript to be sent to the backend.**

```js
function fun(){
    let user = document.getElementById('user').value
    let password = document.getElementById('password').value

    let data = {
        "user": user,
        "password": password
    }
    console.log(data); // this data needs to be sent to the backend
    return true
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
    <title>Data Entry</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <form action="" onsubmit="return fun()">
            <label for="user">user</label>
            <input type="text" name="user" id="user">
            <label for="password">password</label>
            <input type="password" name="password" id="password">
            <input type="submit" value="submit">
        </form>
    </div>
    <script src="code.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use fetch API.

Example, you can use following code inside fun():

```
 fetch('your-python-server', {
        method: 'post',
        body: JSON.stringify(data)
      }).then(function(response) {
        return response.json();
      }).then(function(data) {
        console.log("Data returned from python server", data)
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can stringify your data and send it to the backend.

`JSON.stringify(data)`